# Inject quarkus bean to flyway java based migration

Tags: java, quarkus, flyway

I need to write a migration to flyway using `BaseJavaMigration` or any other approach which allows implementing similar logic.

But I don't have my Quarkus context so I'm not able to do @Inject inside.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.BaseJavaMigration;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.Context;

@ApplicationScoped  // this is not a valid solution
public class V20230329190657__MyMigration extends BaseJavaMigration {

    @Inject         // this is not a valid solution
    MyBean1 myBean1;

    @Inject         // this is not a valid solution
    @RestClient
    MyBean2 myBean2;

    @Override
    public void migrate(Context context) throws Exception {
        // call to myBean1, myBean2 to grab some info
        // HERE will be my migration, Statement, Connection, execution, etc.
    }
}
```

Also if I try to get instances inside `migrate` method in any way like:

```
    MyBean1 myBean1 = CDI.current().select(MyBean1.class).get();
    MyBean2 myBean2 = Arc.container().select(MyBean2.class).get();
```

I'm not able to do it.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to legally @Inject beans into a flyway migration.
So if your migration requires some data from DB - you can get it directly from DB using the connection. In case you need some data from external services - I've decided to use okhttp to grab it.